# FindDivisions behavior changed?

Tags: bugs, documentation

**Bug introduced in 8.0.4 or sooner and fixed in 10.4.1**

---

I seem to recall using `FindDivisions` as a quick way to get all numbers in an interval that are divisible by a member of some set of integers, e.g.

```
FindDivisions[{1,100,{2,3,5}}]
```

gave me lists of all in the range divisible by 2, then 3, then 5, at least if I remember correctly.

Just doing this, I got

> FindDivisions::argtu: FindDivisions called with 1 argument; 2 or 3
>   arguments are expected. >>

A quick look at the docs shows indeed this is the correct format for this operation.

Trying to force the issue with

```
FindDivisions[{1, 100, {2, 3, 5}}, All, 10]
```

resulted in

> FindDivisions::fdargs: The arguments in
>   Developer`FindDivisions[{1,100,{2,3,5}}, All, 10] are not supported.>>

There are of course simple ways to do the same, I'm just curious when this changed (and why it's still documented), or is it a bug and it should work.

Comment: @Lou:Ah, no. That is a completely different result (and documented as such).

Comment: something is wrong here. docs shows your call should work as written. Last entry in help. ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/x3DK9.png) btw, I get same error in V 9 as in V 10.02

Comment: In version 8.0.4 I observe exactly the same behavior as in version 10.0.2.

Comment: Another documented usage  `FindDivisions[{1, 100, {2, 3, 5}}, {30, 50}]` also throws an error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I submitted this issue to the attention of Wolfram tech support. I received their answer this morning. I quote the relevant part.

> I was able to reproduce the issue, and consequently I filed a report with our development team raising the issue.

On the basis of this reply I am tagging the question with [bugs](/questions/tagged/bugs).

Although it is not entirely clear from the brief reply I received, I infer that WRI is treating this as an implementation bug and not as a documentation bug.

Answer (score 2):

From version 10.4.1, the corresponding usage line has been removed,

[image]

and the front end shows that the syntax is incorrect:

[image]