# How to set Ticks for an AngularGauge?

Tags: gui-construction, ticks

How do you set custom ticks on an `AngularGauge`.

```
AngularGauge[π, {0, 2 π}, ScaleOrigin -> {0, 2 π}, 
 ScaleDivisions -> {8, 2}, TargetUnits -> "Radians", 
 GaugeLabels -> "Radians"]
```

[image]

The documentation says it has the same options as `Graphics` but `Ticks` seems to have no effect. I have tried both of the following to get the major ticks:

```
Ticks -> {Range[0, 2 π, π/4], Automatic}
and
Ticks -> {Automatic, Range[0, 2 π, π/4]}
```

I would like to get $\frac{n\pi}{4}$ for $n\in \{0 ...7\}$ as major ticks with `TraditionalForm` labels. Also minor ticks at $\frac{(2n-1)\pi}{8}$ for $n\in \{0 ...7\}$.

Is this possible?

Comment: @MarcoB I'm using `ScaleDivisions` with no joy. Have a look at the code. I'm asking for exactly what I described but it is not cooperating.

Comment: Yes, sorry about that. I realized that as soon as I hit the "Add comment" button :-)

Comment: After playing around a bit, it seems to me that `Gauge` passes the `ScaleDivisions` settings to `FindDivision` to find the positions of the ticks. This would be good news, if it wasn't for the fact that only a subsets of `FindDivision` syntax forms is accepted. For instance, `FindDivisions[{0, 2 Pi, {Pi/4, Pi/8}}, {8, 2}]` would generate the ticks that you like, but that syntax is not supported in `ScaleDivisions`.

Comment: @MarcoB `FindDivisions[{0, 2 Pi, {Pi/4, Pi/8}}]` will work after its [bug is fixed](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/78573). I'll revisit this and try `ScaleDivisions -> {0, 2 Pi, {Pi/4, Pi/8}}`. Maybe it will work then.

Comment: In my opinion `ScaleDivisions` is equivalent to the *second* argument of `FindDivisions`. In this connection, although the one-argument version you mention does not work, the two-argument version does: `FindDivisions[{0, 2 Pi, {Pi/4, Pi/8}}, {5, 4}]`. Unfortunately one cannot specify increments in the `Gauge` range as you would in `FindDivisions` though. Or am I misunderstanding your point? In any case, I hope they fix / extend the gauge functionality!